# IIS doesn't interpret a php file

Tags: php, iis

I have a IIS webserver (v 6.1) with a webpage which is accessable from other devices in the LAN. If I try to access a php-page via the IP address I can only download the file. IIS doesn't interpret the PHP.
When I access the page locally (with a specified hostname like 'http://test.app') everything works fine.

Are there any settings to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within the PHP file as it returns JSON or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In default IIS server doesn't parse php content and

you must configure your IIS server to parse and render PHP content.

Please read this [setup tutorial](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/installing_php_5_iis_5_simple_steps)

or just google for [configuring iis for php](http://www.google.com/search?q=configuring%20iis%20for%20php)

Comment: I have installed the PHPManager and PHP version 5.3.5 is used, so PHP works fine if I call the php-file locally via a host name. The problem exists only when I try to access the site from another PC inside the LAN over the IP.